# Can't find default Subclipse configuration location: why?

Tags: svn, subclipse

In my personal machine (windows 7) I can find subclipse's configuration folder under:
C:\Users\My-User\AppData\Roaming\Subversion

however, under the machine I'm working on (windows 7 as well), the "Subversion" folder cannot seem to be found.
Subclipse is already installed and seem working, but I need to set some proxy preferences and I can't find them!

Answer (score 1):

It is Subversion, not Subclipse that writes to this location.  On Windows, the location is %APPDATA%\Subversion.  You can enter that in the Windows Run/Open dialog and it will open explorer to whatever the right folder location is.

Comment: in my case `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion`